# Assembly Programming using SASM on Windows, with an example using int 0x80 (Linux system calls)

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I need help. I'm  trying to run the program (NASM) below in SASM.

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data 

   msg1 db "Enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD 
   len1 equ $- msg1 

   msg2 db "Please enter a second digit", 0xA,0xD 
   len2 equ $- msg2 

   msg3 db "The sum is: "
   len3 equ $- msg3

segment .bss

   num1 resb 2 
   num2 resb 2 
   res resb 1    

section .text
   global _start    ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:             ;tell linker entry point
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg1         
   mov edx, len1 
   int 0x80                

   mov eax, SYS_READ 
   mov ebx, STDIN  
   mov ecx, num1 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80            

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg2          
   mov edx, len2         
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_READ  
   mov ebx, STDIN  
   mov ecx, num2 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80        

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg3          
   mov edx, len3         
   int 0x80

   ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
   ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number

   mov eax, [num1]
   sub eax, '0'

   mov ebx, [num2]
   sub ebx, '0'

   ; add eax and ebx
   add eax, ebx
   ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
   add eax, '0'

   ; storing the sum in memory location res
   mov [res], eax

   ; print the sum 
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
   mov ebx, STDOUT
   mov ecx, res         
   mov edx, 1        
   int 0x80

exit:    

   mov eax, SYS_EXIT   
   xor ebx, ebx 
   int 0x80
```

I had this error:

> [20:53:11] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
>   c:/program files (x86)/sasm/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function 'main':
>   C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Also, how do  I limit users input up to 4 digits only?

Comment: First thing is that you are using`int 0x80` for system calls (and it appears you are using Linux ones). Those won't work with Windows. Don't use Linux tutorials when writing Windows assembly programs.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Can you advise what to do  to make  that work in windows? I just got that code from Tutorialspoint which says it would work for both.

Comment: SASM has `io.inc` which has a number of NASM macros for doing basic input and output. https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html

Comment: If the person who wrote the tutorial you're reading is unaware of basic differences between the Windows and Linux operating systems, you are probably wasting your time by bothering to read that tutorial. If you want to learn Windows assembly programming, read a more appropriate tutorial. There are lots of good ones, findable with a Google search, like [this one](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf) or [Iczelion's](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html).

Answer (score 0):

global _start should change to global main and Linux system calls should be replaced by [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function calls and declared as external. Modern versions of Windows doesn't approve use of system calls due to malware or badware risks, so deprecated (permanent) system call codes. Every modern version of Windows has different system call number codes, though you can find them on internet, you shouldn't rely on them unless you want to revise your assembly code for each version of Windows thus reducing portability and increasing workload. There are significant [differences](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2017/fall/cs301/reference/x86_64.html) between Linux/Mac and Windows in the way of handling registers, stack and function names.

Comment: Do you have any source explaining that Windows doesn't expose the hardware syscall interface because of "malware risks"?

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more appropriate. I don't have complete understanding of why using permanent sys call code numbers cause increased vulnerability, but I have read it in couple of web sites though I don't exactly remember all the places here is one link (It mentions it but do not describe mechanism) https://www.cs.uaf.edu/courses/cs301/2014-fall/notes/syscall/

Comment: Is this a reason for changing sys call numbers between versions? https://www.cyberbit.com/endpoint-security/malware-mitigation-when-direct-system-calls-are-used/

Comment: @xiver77: That claim about malware is nonsense.  The ABI isn't fully stable between Windows versions, but nothing stops user-space code from using `syscall` or `int 0x2e` directly to invoke the NT API with the right call numbers for the current kernel version.  So targeted malware has no problem, it's mostly portable software that's inconvenienced.  See https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/win32k/64/ for reverse-engineered call numbers.

Comment: @xiver77: I suspect most of the reason for not providing a stable system-call ABI and wanting all programs to go through DLLs is that it increases MS's ability to provide bug-compatibility for old binaries, by having DLL versions that emulate old behaviours.  Keeping that in user-space DLLs keeps it out of the kernel, perhaps making it easier to maintain that codebase.